# Packaged JSON file in WAR not picked up on AWS

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, war

I have a springboot application that reads a bunch of JSON files in

> src/main/resources/shops

using this code:

```
File(javaClass.getResource("/shops/").path).walkTopDown().forEach {
```

When I run this locally, with

> clean bootRun

the code runs fine, and I get results from the query that parses these files.

However upon building a WAR file with

> clean build war

and deploying it to AWS's EC2 instance, I get no results which I'm presuming is because the files aren't being picked up.

I renamed the .war to .zip to examine it and I couldn't find the json files (unless they've been renamed and moved). How can I ensure the files are packaged properly in the WAR?

Edit: Have now confirmed the issue is that the server deployed WAR isn't reading any files, whereas the local run instance is.

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? Can you post your build script?

Comment: @dunni gradle   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `bootRun`, it finds `/shop` under `build/classes`, so `path` would give you the local file system path, which works naturally with `File`. However when packaged in a WAR file, the `path` of a resource found inside the WAR is no longer a valid file system path. It would be encoded with the path of the WAR file, and the path to the resource inside the WAR.

To make it work, instead of `File`, use `javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/shop/somefile.json")` and read from the `InputStream` returned.

Your next problem will be that with `File` you can walk the directory tree and automatically get all the json files under `/shop/`. Now you can't because there isn't a file system directory to walk through. You'll need to use one of those libraries for finding wildcard resources on the classpath. For instance, Spring lets you load all resources matching `/shop/**/*.json`.

Comment: thank you! That's really helpful. I did try the stream option but got stuck with, as you say, not being able to get a list of directories. Are you saying that javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/shop/*.json") should work? What I'm then doing is jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<Shop>(it.absoluteFile, Shop::class.java) so I need to somehow map the IS to an Object

Comment: Well, `javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/shop/*.json")` won't work. There isn't a core Java API that automatically discovers resources by wildcard. You'll need to search for a library to do that. If you are already using Spring in your app, then you can just use Spring's resource loading as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I marked this as my answer as you mentioned the Spring resource loading, but I actually didn't use the stream method, I used  resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/shops.json")